# How to use azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-servicebus-queue to accept messages without deprecated class Checkpointer

Tags: java, azure, kotlin, azure-servicebus-queues

We use the java library azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-servicebus-queue in version 2.11.0 to receive messages from an Azure service bus. We have an implementation according to the recipe recommended at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-with-service-bus dating from
11/08/2021. It works fine, but uses the deprecated class com.azure.spring.integration.core.api.Checkpointer.

Is there a way to receive messages without using this deprecated class? Links to examples are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Same here.
I changed to the new version (4.0.0-beta.2) of the Spring Cloud Azure.

In this docs there are some examples/guides to migrate:

- https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/current/reference/html/index.html
- https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/current/reference/html/appendix.html#migration-guide-for-4-0

And a explanation about the versions:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Spring-Versions-Mapping

Comment: Thanks for the links, Rafael. I can open the one with the version mapping but get 404 for the first two links. Are they correct or are special rights required to open them?

Comment: I believe they changed the folder.
I edited and they are correct now. (I removed the "docs" from the url) This is the root link in case you need it:
https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/